# Group java string based on nth word in Camel case

Tags: java, string

I want to group certain java strings into subset of strings with same nth word.

Eg List:

CorePlatformPortal,
CorePlatformRuntime,
CorePlatformRuntimeConfiguration,
DetailPageAlternative,
DetailPageBooks,
DetailBuild,
HorizontePage,
HorizontePageLogging,
HorizonteBuild,

Input : 1

Output:

CorePlatformPortal, CorePlatformRuntime, CorePlatformRuntimeConfiguration ||
DetailPageAlternative, DetailPageBooks, DetailBuild ||
HorizontePage, HorizontePageLogging, HorizonteBuild

Explanation- Grouped based on Core, Detail, Horizonte

Input : 2

Output:

CorePlatformPortal, CorePlatformRuntime, CorePlatformRuntimeConfiguration ||
DetailPageAlternative, DetailPageBooks, HorizontePage, HorizontePageLogging ||
DetailBuild, HorizonteBuild

Explanation- Grouped based on Platform, Page, Build

Any leads are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: What happens e.g. if a certain word has both `Core` and `Detail` in it?  What does the output look like in this case?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen, so either Core will be nth word or Detail will be, so according to n it will give the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make grouping using Stream API and splitting initial strings into array of words using Regexp:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("CorePlatformPortal",
                                  "CorePlatformRuntime",
                                  "CorePlatformRuntimeConfiguration",
                                  "DetailPageAlternative",
                                  "DetailPageBooks",
                                  "DetailBuild",
                                  "HorizontePage",
                                  "HorizontePageLogging",
                                  "HorizonteBuild");
int input = 2;

Map<String, List<String>> output =  
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str.split("(?=[A-Z])")[input-1]));

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Can i also split based on spcl characters like "-" ? Along with Capital Letters? @Sergey Afinogenov

Comment: Eg: "Abc-asD",
                "Abc-pCD",
                "Abc-ghS",
                "AbcA",
                "AbcUW" Should all be grouped together

Comment: @Indradeep Hayaran Yes just change regular expression into "(?=[A-Z])|-"